# the limit clause with postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

how can I transform this mysql limit clause for Postgresql:

```
limit $a,$b
```

when possible not a specific postgresql solution but rather a sql standard

Query failed: ERREUR:  la syntaxe LIMIT #,# n'est pas supportée

**EDITION**

```
"select * from preference where (id_membre ='184') order by 1 LIMIT 0 OFFSET 8";
```

return 4 rows with mysql, 0 rows with postgresl !

Comment: A simple look at the fine manual would have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The Postgres syntax is `limit x offset y` as explained [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-limit.html).

If you still have a problem with the variables, you can replace this with a `where` clause.  If you have a query like this:

```
select . . .
order by <something>
```

You can get what you want with:

```
select t.*  -- or list of columns without seqnum
from (select . . ., row_number() over (order by <something>) as seqnum
     ) t
where seqnum between $a and $a + $b
```

Comment: after a few tests, it seems that limit $a,$b cannot be translated in limit $a offset $b (see my edition). And why this -1 ?!

Answer (score 1):

Limit 0 is doing exactly what it says it is doing.  Limiting to 0 rows!  The query probably runs really fast too!

It isn't surprising to me at all that PostgreSQL has a very literal view of what `limit 0` means.  Nor, unfortunately, is it surprising to me that MySQL has a rather idiosyncratic view of the same